# ASP.NET DataTables render Incorrect DateTime value from database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, database, datatable

I want to render a DateTime column in an ASP.NET MVC datatable with the correct data. Datetime is being parsed from a database.

Instead of showing the correct date and time, it displays this `/Date(-62135596800000)/`

Here is my model

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Office { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Salary { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> End { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult GetData()
{
    using (MyDatabaseEntities1 db = new MyDatabaseEntities1())
    {
        List<Employee> empList = db.Employees.ToList<Employee>();
        return Json(new { data = empList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Thirdly my index view. Please focus on the "Start" attribute.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee List"; 
}
 
<h2>Employee CRUD Operations</h2>

<a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px"
   onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Employee")')">
   <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New
</a> 
<table id="employeeTable"
       class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Position</th>
           <th>Office</th>
           <th>Age</th>
           <th>Salary</th>
           <th>Start</th>
           <th>End</th>
           <th></th>
       </tr>
    </thead> 
</table>
 
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 
@section scripts {
     <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
     <script>
         var Popup, dataTable;
         $(document).ready(function () {
             dataTable =  $("#employeeTable").DataTable({
                 "ajax": {
                     "url": "/Employee/GetData",
               "type": "GET",
               "datatype": "json"
           },
           "columns": [
               { "data": "Name" },
               { "data": "Position" },
               { "data": "Office" },
               { "data": "Age" },
               { "data": "Salary" },
               {"data": "Start"},
               { "data": "End" },
               {"data":"EmployeeID" , "render" : function (data) {
                   return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' 
      onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Employee")/" + data +
      "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a><a class='btn btn-danger
       btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' onclick=Delete("+data+")><i class='fa
       fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>";
               },               
                   "orderable": false,
                   "searchable":false,
                   "width":"150px"
               }],
           "language": {

               "emptyTable" : "No data found, Please click on <b>Add New</b> Button"
           }

       });
});
```

Lastly the first screenshot represents the database:

[image]

This database represents the web app. As you can see it wont display the dates and time instead only /Date(-62135596800000)/. Notice how all the other data displays correctly

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: You have to convert Datetime to string in the format you need. You should not expose your database model, map it to another object (MVC pattern) and make the conversion in the mapping.

Comment: The value `-62135596800000` evaluates to the date `Monday, January 1, 0001 12:00:00 AM GMT` when [converted](https://www.epochconverter.com/) from an epoch timestamp to a date.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a String Date autogenerated column:

   ```
   public partial class Employee
   {
       public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Position { get; set; }
       public string Office { get; set; }
       public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
       public Nullable<int> Salary { get; set; }        
       public System.DateTime Start { get; set; }
       public Nullable<System.DateTime> End { get; set; }
       public string EndDateString { get { return End?.ToShortDateString(); } } 
   }
   ```
2. Use that field instead of `End`

   ```
    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Employee List"; 
    }

    <h2>Employee CRUD Operations</h2>

    <a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px"
      onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Employee")')">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New
    </a> 
    <table id="employeeTable"
      class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
          <th>Start</th>
          <th>End</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead> 
   </table>  
   <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

   @section scripts {
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var Popup, dataTable;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            dataTable =  $("#employeeTable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Employee/GetData",
              "type": "GET",
              "datatype": "json"
          },
          "columns": [
              { "data": "Name" },
              { "data": "Position" },
              { "data": "Office" },
              { "data": "Age" },
              { "data": "Salary" },
              {"data": "Start"},
              { "data": "EndDateString" },
              {"data":"EmployeeID" , "render" : function (data) {
                  return "<a class='btn btn-default btn-sm' 
     onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Employee")/" + data +
     "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a><a class='btn btn-danger
      btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' onclick=Delete("+data+")><i class='fa
      fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>";
              },               
                  "orderable": false,
                  "searchable":false,
                  "width":"150px"
              }],
          "language": {

              "emptyTable" : "No data found, Please click on <b>Add New</b> Button"
          }

      });
   });
   ```